# Nodejs and Mongoose data fetching

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have some problem with data fetching.

I have mongoose scheme.

```js
PostSchema.methods.getAuthor = function () {
    this.model('User').findById(this.author).exec(function (err, author){
        if (author) {
            console.log(author.username);
            return author.username;
        };
    });
};

mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

and getMethod

```js
exports.getPost = function (req, res) {
    return Post.findById(req.params.id, function (err, post) {
        if (!post) {
            res.statusCode = 404;
            return res.send({ error: 'Not found' });
        }
        if (!err) {
            var author = post.getAuthor();
            console.log('author is: ', author);

            return res.send({ status: 'OK', post:post });
        } else {
            res.statusCode = 500;
            return res.send({ error: 'Server error' });
        }
    });
};
```

When I call `post.getAuthor()` inside `getPost` method he is work and found User by Id. But `var author = post.getAuthor();` have `undefined` value.

Comment: Of course you get `undefined` as you are trying to assign the value of asynchronous `getAuthor` function synchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @zaynetro mentioned you're calling your `getAuthor` method incorrectly. It's an asynchronous method, so you should be accepting a callback parameter, or you could return a promise.

But what you're trying to do is already built in to mongoose, its called query population.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

You can configure a Post.author reference property that you can have mongoose resolve into the document for you.

```
var postSchema = Schema({
    author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});
mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

var userSchma = Schema({
    name: String
});
mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Then, in your route your query would look like this:

```
Post
    .findById(req.params.id)
    .populate('author')
    .exec(function(err, post) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send({
                error: 'Server error'
            });
        }
        // post.author contains the content of your author document
        return res.send(post);
    });
```